# Generate Prisma schema without DB, only 3rd party REST API

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma

May I generate Prisma schema (typeDefs) without endpoint to db?
I got a situation when

- I want to create graphql middleware
- This middleware is communicating with rest API by 3rd party provider so I don't want to create my own DB, but I would like to have these helper functions which Prisma can generate base on my schema types.

Is that possible??
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If possible, it had to be mentioned [here](https://www.prisma.io/blog/how-to-wrap-a-rest-api-with-graphql-8bf3fb17547d/)?

You're probably searching for [generators](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-cli-and-configuration/cli-command-reference-xcv9/#prisma-generate)? Generate `graphql-schema` from datamodel (types) then implement resolvers.

Comment: yeah I just need to generate "helper functions" from types to save time and the most important have that nice structure which prisma generate :)
I will check this! 
Thanks so much :)

Comment: okay the documentation looks good but when I run `prisma generate` it tells me:
generate is not a prisma command

Comment: ask project maintainers on github?